# Object is possibly 'null' with type 'as HTMLInputElement' but not 'any'

Tags: typescript

I have a method in Typescript that validates file size and file type with regards to upload.

However, I get an "Object is possibly 'null.' error whenever I run my code on VSCode. It happens on this specific line:

```
    const FileSize = (document.getElementById('fileName')as HTMLInputElement).files[0].size;
```

However, when I change the line to

```
    const FileSize = (document.getElementById('fileName')as any).files[0].size;
```

It seems to work and the TypeScript error is suppressed. I have no idea why, and I'd love to be enlightened as to why this happens. This is the full method below:

```
  private validateFileType() {
    // Checks if file is .xsx or .xlsx
    const masterFile = (document.getElementById('fileName')as HTMLInputElement).value;
    const idxDot = masterFile.lastIndexOf('.') + 1;
    const fileType = masterFile.substr(idxDot, masterFile.length).toLowerCase();

    // Checks if file size is less than or equal to 5MB
    const maxAllowedSize = 5 * 1024 * 1024;
    const FileSize = (document.getElementById('fileName')as HTMLInputElement).files[0].size;

    if (fileType !== 'xls' && fileType !== 'xlsx' ) {
      // Alert code here
    }
    if (FileSize > maxAllowedSize) {
      // Alert code here
    }
  }
```

I've read that using `any` or casting in order to "trick" the compiler defeats the purpose of using Typescript, so any help or hints would be appreciated!

Comment: Use a type parameter to `querySelector` instead

Comment: Unfortunately still getting the same error with ```querySelector```.

Comment: You'll need the type parameter, and then to check that the element really exists before doing something with it, or use `!`

Comment: Will try to use that, thanks! Although I was wondering why the previous ```masterFile``` line did not return the same error even if it's a bit similar.

Comment: Because `as` also somewhat disables type-checking - but generics (type parameters) are better.